# Within a JavaScript function how do I know if I was invoked with new?

Tags: javascript

If I have function:

```
function Thing( name_of_thing )
{
    this.name = name_of_thing;
}
```

Is there a way to know if invoked by:

```
var my_thing = new Thing( 'Something' ); // result: { name: "Something" }
```

versus:

```
var my_thing = Thing( 'Something' ); // result: undefined
```

Comment: yes. the question is: when do you want to know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function Thing(nameOfThing) {
  if (this == window) throw new Error("Must be constructed with new!");
  this.name = nameOfThing;
}

var myThing = new Thing("Something"); // Thing {name: "Something"}
var myThing = Thing("Something"); // error
```

Basically we're comparing `this` with the global `window` object. If they are the same (hence `==`) then throw an error if they are the same.

---

You could also figure it out by checking if `this` is an instance of `Thing`:

```
function Thing(nameOfThing) {
  if (!(this instanceof Thing)) throw new Error("Must be instance of Thing!");
  this.name = nameOfThing;
}
```

This is slightly better because it will only allow any instance of `Thing` or an instance of a child class of `Thing`.

---

It's a very good idea you remembered to keep this in mind because otherwise you'll be setting attributes of `window` - so `window.name` will be `"Something"`!

Comment: @whatwasthat I believe that kind of defensive programming should be avoided. Using tools to control code quality, such as jshint would warn about those errors automatically.